# Need to restructure data received from web into excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have a excel macro that searches many values in a column and puts the data into another worksheet. However the data is scattered and need to arrange it.

Here is the macro im using

```
Sub Search()
    Dim i As Integer, n As Integer, SearchString As String, ws As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim iRet As Integer
    Dim strPrompt As String
    Dim strTitle As String

    strPrompt = "Hit OK when you wish to proceed to the next search item."
    strTitle = "Next Search"

    Set ws = Sheets("FINAL")
    Set ws2 = Sheets("AllData")
    n = ws.Range("C2").End(xlDown).Row

    For i = 2 To n
        SearchString = ws.Cells(i, 3).Value
        With Worksheets("Query").QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
            "URL;https://www.*****.com/catalog/***.hsm?ItemNumber=" & SearchString _
            , Destination:=Worksheets("Query").Range("A1"))
            .Name = SearchString
            .FieldNames = True
            .RowNumbers = False
            .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
            .PreserveFormatting = False
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
            .BackgroundQuery = True
            .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
            .SavePassword = True
            .SaveData = True
            .AdjustColumnWidth = True
            .RefreshPeriod = 0
            .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
            .WebTables = "1"
            .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
            .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
            .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
            .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
            .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
            .WebDisableRedirections = False
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        End With


    iRet = MsgBox(strPrompt, vbYesNo, strTitle)
    If iRet = vbNo Then
        End
    Else

    End If

    Next i
End Sub
```

Here is how the data is being set in my sheet

[image]

I would like to have anything that starts with the following put in columns
Crosses To:
Replaces:
Crossed From:

Also, I have my .Name set to my searchString and .FieldNames set to true but they are not showing up.

The end result i would like to have is this

```
+---------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
- SearchString  -     Sub      -     Sub      -     Sub      -
+---------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
-   AR34567     -   A-TY25993  -              -              -
-   AR11160     -    TS-1087   -   AR11300    -   D2-0099N   -
+---------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
```

There would be more sub column's for AR11160, just put a few in the table above to give you the idea what i want.

**UPDATE**

I was able to start tweaking the data as I need it. However, I can only seem to get the number i need on the same row. On the image above you see that column K has many numbers under Crossed From:. So I need to bring all those numbers too.

Please help

```
Sub Search2()
    Dim i As Integer, n As Integer, SearchString As String
    Dim shFinal As Worksheet, shQuery As Worksheet, shAllData As Worksheet
    Dim iRet As Integer
    Dim strPrompt As String
    Dim strTitle As String
    Dim m As Long, p As Long, q As Long, r As Long

    Dim vSrc As Variant, vDest() As Variant
    Dim r1 As Range
    Dim Blank As String


    strPrompt = "Hit OK when you wish to proceed to the next search item."
    strTitle = "Next Search"

    Set shFinal = Sheets("FINAL")
    Set shQuery = Sheets("Query")
    Set shAllData = Sheets("AllData")

    n = shFinal.Range("C2").End(xlDown).Row
    q = 1

    For i = 2 To n
        SearchString = shFinal.Cells(i, 3).Value
        Set qt = shQuery.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
            "URL;https://www.***.com/catalog/***.hsm?ItemNumber=" & SearchString _
            , Destination:=Worksheets("Query").Range("A1"))
        With qt
            .Name = SearchString
            .FieldNames = True
            .RowNumbers = False
            .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
            .PreserveFormatting = False
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
            .BackgroundQuery = True
            .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
            .SavePassword = True
            .SaveData = True
            .AdjustColumnWidth = True
            .RefreshPeriod = 0
            .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
            .WebTables = "1"
            .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
            .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
            .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
            .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
            .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
            .WebDisableRedirections = False
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        End With

    shAllData.Cells(q, 1) = SearchString

        p = 1
        Do While p < 30

        If shQuery.Cells(p, 4) Like "Replaces:*" Then shAllData.Cells(q, p) = shQuery.Cells(p, 5)

        If shQuery.Cells(p, 4) Like "Crossed From:*" Then shAllData.Cells(q, p) = shQuery.Cells(p, 5)

        If shQuery.Cells(p, 4) Like "Crosses To:*" Then shAllData.Cells(q, p) = shQuery.Cells(p, 5)

        p = p + 1
        Loop

    iRet = MsgBox(strPrompt, vbYesNo, strTitle)
    If iRet = vbNo Then
        End
    Else
        shQuery.UsedRange.ClearContents
    End If

    q = q + 1
    Next i


End Sub
```

**ANOTHER UPDATE**
Another Update

I know have the data being placed like i want it. Just have one issue. When a value is searched and not found i get a error on this line [.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False]

How can i tell this code if a result is not returned skip it?

```
Sub Search2()
    Dim i As Integer, n As Integer, SearchString As String
    Dim shFinal As Worksheet, shQuery As Worksheet, shAllData As Worksheet
    Dim iRet As Integer
    Dim strPrompt As String
    Dim strTitle As String
    Dim m As Long, p As Long, q As Long, r As Long, s As Long
    Dim range As range
    Dim vSrc As Variant, vDest() As Variant
    Dim r1 As range

    strPrompt = "Hit OK when you wish to proceed to the next search item."
    strTitle = "Next Search"

    Set shFinal = Sheets("FINAL")
    Set shQuery = Sheets("Query")
    Set shAllData = Sheets("AllData")

    n = shFinal.range("C2").End(xlDown).Row
    q = 1

    For i = 2 To n
        SearchString = shFinal.Cells(i, 3).Value
        Set qt = shQuery.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
            "URL;https://www.***.com/catalog/***.hsm?ItemNumber=" & SearchString _
            , Destination:=Worksheets("Query").range("A1"))
        With qt
            .Name = SearchString
            .FieldNames = True
            .RowNumbers = False
            .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
            .PreserveFormatting = False
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
            .BackgroundQuery = True
            .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
            .SavePassword = True
            .SaveData = True
            .AdjustColumnWidth = True
            .RefreshPeriod = 0
            .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
            .WebTables = "1"
            .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
            .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
            .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
            .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
            .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
            .WebDisableRedirections = False
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        End With

        shAllData.Cells(q, 1) = SearchString

        p = 1
        Do While p < 30

        If shQuery.Cells(p, 4) Like "Replaces:*" Then shAllData.Cells(q, p) = shQuery.Cells(p, 5)

        If shQuery.Cells(p, 4) Like "Crossed From:*" Then shAllData.Cells(q, p) = shQuery.Cells(p, 5)

        If shQuery.Cells(p, 4) Like "Crosses To:*" Then shAllData.Cells(q, p) = shQuery.Cells(p, 5)

        Set range = shQuery.range("E2:E25")

        For Each cell In range

            If IsEmpty(cell) Then
                Exit For
            Else
                r = p + 1
                shAllData.Cells(q, r) = shQuery.Cells(r, 5)
            End If
        Next

        p = p + 1
        Loop

    iRet = MsgBox(strPrompt, vbYesNo, strTitle)
    If iRet = vbNo Then
        shQuery.UsedRange.ClearContents
        End
    Else
        shQuery.UsedRange.ClearContents
    End If


    q = q + 1
    Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: updated question with more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your latest updated question

> *I know have the data being placed like i want it. Just have one issue. When a value is searched and not found i get a error on this line [.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False]*
>
> *How can i tell this code if a result is not returned skip it?*

Below is your complete code with an error handler.

I added an `On Error Resume Next` statement before the line `.Refresh BackgroundQuery`.

After that, it checks if an error has occurred:

If not it executes your code, like it does now.

If yes, then it skips your code, resets the error handler, and goes to the next *i*.

```
    Sub Search2()
    Dim i As Integer, n As Integer, SearchString As String
    Dim shFinal As Worksheet, shQuery As Worksheet, shAllData As Worksheet
    Dim iRet As Integer
    Dim strPrompt As String
    Dim strTitle As String
    Dim m As Long, p As Long, q As Long, r As Long, s As Long
    Dim range As range
    Dim vSrc As Variant, vDest() As Variant
    Dim r1 As range

    strPrompt = "Hit OK when you wish to proceed to the next search item."
    strTitle = "Next Search"

    Set shFinal = Sheets("FINAL")
    Set shQuery = Sheets("Query")
    Set shAllData = Sheets("AllData")

    n = shFinal.range("C2").End(xlDown).Row
    q = 1

    For i = 2 To n
        SearchString = shFinal.Cells(i, 3).Value
        Set qt = shQuery.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
            "URL;https://www.***.com/catalog/***.hsm?ItemNumber=" & SearchString _
            , Destination:=Worksheets("Query").range("A1"))
        
        With qt
            .Name = SearchString
            .FieldNames = True
            .RowNumbers = False
            .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
            .PreserveFormatting = False
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
            .BackgroundQuery = True
            .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
            .SavePassword = True
            .SaveData = True
            .AdjustColumnWidth = True
            .RefreshPeriod = 0
            .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
            .WebTables = "1"
            .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
            .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
            .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
            .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
            .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
            .WebDisableRedirections = False
            
            On Error Resume Next '<-- Added line
            
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        End With

        If Err = 0 Then '<-- Added line

            On Error Goto 0 '<-- Added line
        
            shAllData.Cells(q, 1) = SearchString
    
            p = 1
            Do While p < 30
    
            If shQuery.Cells(p, 4) Like "Replaces:*" Then shAllData.Cells(q, p) = shQuery.Cells(p, 5)
    
            If shQuery.Cells(p, 4) Like "Crossed From:*" Then shAllData.Cells(q, p) = shQuery.Cells(p, 5)
    
            If shQuery.Cells(p, 4) Like "Crosses To:*" Then shAllData.Cells(q, p) = shQuery.Cells(p, 5)
    
            Set range = shQuery.range("E2:E25")
    
            For Each cell In range
    
                If IsEmpty(cell) Then
                    Exit For
                Else
                    r = p + 1
                    shAllData.Cells(q, r) = shQuery.Cells(r, 5)
                End If
            Next
    
            p = p + 1
            Loop
    
            iRet = MsgBox(strPrompt, vbYesNo, strTitle)
            If iRet = vbNo Then
                shQuery.UsedRange.ClearContents
                End
            Else
                shQuery.UsedRange.ClearContents
            End If
    
    
            q = q + 1
            
        End If  '<-- Added line
        
        Err = 0 '<-- Added line
    Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I was trying to implement this but was putting it in the wrong place :)

Comment: One question. When the error is caught (a number is not found) it seems to take a long time until it goes to the next. Any idea why?

Comment: Acutally it seems its taking a lot longer to find the numbers. before it moved pretty quickly

Comment: If you run the initial and revised code one after another, do you still see difference in performance? Have you run through your code step-by-step, with F8? Which step is now taking longer than before? Is there another way to check if the value does not exist?